# SQL Order by descending total last

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, netezza

I would like to set my order by to descending but with my total row(sums up all numerical values in a specific column) as last row as last in sequence, is this possible?

DB is netezza, and there are only three columns: ID, name and revenue which is an aggregated column to begin with

Comment: What flavor and version of SQL?

Comment: Regardless, you could always set up that total in a subquery and then order the outer query by the sum in the subquery.

Comment: Where is your code?could you show us?

Comment: Actually, since most SQL flavors will process an `ORDER BY` after a `SELECT`, you should be able to just do a simple `ORDER BY` on the alias you summed the column on.

Comment: Also, can you provide an example of the data you start with and your expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT column_A , column_B , ... {your query}

UNION ALL 

SELECT '' as Column_A , SUM(column_B) as column_B,... {your totals query}
```

`column_B` in this case can be whichever numerical column that you want totals for. `column_A` is a non-numerical column or any column you do not want a total for. Note that all columns `selected` in `{your totals query}` should be `aggregated` or `NULL` if you want this to return only a single row.

You will also need to include the same number of columns in both queries for the `UNION` method to work properly.

If you include your `RMDB`, then we can tailor a more specific solution. `UNION ALL` is the syntax for `SQL-Server`.

-- so in response to your comment 9/6, it sounds like you can run an `offset` `fetch` command.

```
SELECT {your query} OFFSET 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT {your query} OFFSET 0 FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
```

Keep the `ORDER BY` the same for both queries or you will get unexpected results.

Comment: You shouldn't need a `UNION ALL`. This should be able to be done with simply a `SUM(colA+colB+colC)`.

Comment: Wording on the original is a bit unclear. It sounds like John wants a format similar to an access table totals column. Where `Totals` would be an additional row appended to the end of the results-set that contained the aggregated values for specific columns.

Comment: Edward, sorry for any confusion but yes you are correct.  I can create a totals row using grouping sets.  And i am ordering by revenue descending(which is already summed), i would just like the total row to be at the bottom instead of the top as it is currently complying with the order descending order by statement

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit. I'm not really sure what `Netezza` runs on the back-end, but if it existed before 2010, then `sql-server` is a good bet. If that's the case, then you should have no trouble executing this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle was created in MySQL, but the query should work in any standard SQL.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5cb6a2/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( id int, name varchar(10), revenue int ) ;

INSERT INTO t1 (id, name, revenue)
VALUES (1,'first',10), (2,'first',10), (3,'last',1), (4,'last',1) ;
```

**Main Query**:

```
SELECT name, sum(revenue) AS totalRevenue
FROM t1
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY totalRevenue DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5cb6a2/1/0)**:

```
|  name | totalRevenue |
|-------|--------------|
| first |           20 |
|  last |            2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `grouping sets`:

```
select id, name, sum(revenue)
from t
group by grouping sets ( (id, name), () )
order by (case when grouping(id) = 1 then 1 else 2 end) desc,
         sum(revenue) desc;
```